# Parse text file that has delimiters but non-CRLF line separator (using vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

`VB.FileIO.TextFieldParser` seems to require or assume that each line of text in a file is separated by `CRLF`. I need to parse data from a file that has comma-delimited data ... but lines are separated by an exclamation point (`!`) at the start of each line.

Can someone show how to parse each line, one at a time, into a string and display in a text box? Data items may contain spaces and may contain negative values.

Sample TXT data file:

```
!1,2.2,3.33,4.444,5,66,-77,  8,-9.992,2.3,3.34,4.555,5,66,-78,  9,-9.99!1,2.2,3.33,4.444,5,66,-77,  8,-9.99!1,2.2,3.33,4.444,5,66,-77,  8,-9.99
```

Comment: So, does the source file have just one line of text? Do you also need to remove the spaces? Have you tried something to achieve this result?

Comment: @Jimi The source file has many, many lines but they are separated by (!) and not by (CRLF). I have a TextFieldParser solution that works for similar files with CRLF but it won't work for (!). I'm not worried about the spaces at this point, just mentioning that nature of the data (see my original, unedited post). I'm mostly looking for a method to extract the strings between (!), one at a time for display and for send to a serial port. (For this question though, I just need a method to extract the strings ... Thanks!

Comment: You didn't answer any of the questions. Does you file have just one line of text (meaning, all you have in the file is **ONE physical** line of text)? Do you need to remove the spaces (meaning, it's important that you say *Yes* or *No*; the final result depends on this, too)?

Comment: @Jimi Yes, there is just one physical line of text with (!) to indicate where the data starts to repeat but no CRLF to physically create line breaks. No, the spaces do not need to be removed.

Comment: Then, give or take, what's shown in the answer here. You can split the string you get from the File (using `File.ReadAllText()` or anything else) using `!` as separator. This will give you an Array or a List of strings. You can use the Array or the List index position (e.g., `List(0)`, `List(1)` etc.) to read each line of text generated by the Split() method and assign the string (or all the strings) to whatever control you like. If you need to show all the lines in one control only, use, for example,  `TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, [Your Array or List])`

Comment: @Jimi - thanks for your quick responses and patience. I'll mark this as answered and play with the "String.Split" method. Cheers.

Comment: @Jimi. By the way, I hadn't considered parsing the entire file into an array in one step before because I assumed a large file would overload the array - and that it would be necessary, or safer, to pluck one row at a time from between the line-separators. Apparently that is not the case but I'll try my largest sample files to see if even very large files can be Split like this.

Comment: Well, how large is *large* in bytes? A 64bit process can hold a lot of bytes :) But, of course, you don't want to waste memory if not necessary. The File content could be parsed in different ways, if required. Anyway, you said the you want to show the content in a TextBox control, so this could be the actual problem.

Comment: @Jimi. I'll guesstimate 1 MB to 10 MB for largest file that might occur. Agreed on not wasting memory; I prefer to play it safe and assume VERY large files. Output to Text control was just an example and to limit scope of my question, which was originally to parse each line to a text box one at a time, with a button press. I would be interested in an alternate method that would search through the file for the ! character, parse the CSV data to a string, and then move to the next ! until EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the text file with ! as delimiter, like this.

```
  Dim str As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
  Dim arr() As String = str.Split("!")
  For Each s As String In arr
      Textbox1.Text &= s & vbNewLine
  Next
```